# Rails 4 rspec 3 controller test: session helper module not working for before(:all), works for before(:each)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm building a toy chat application using Rails 4.2.7, and am writing specs for my controllers using rspec 3.5.  My `Api::ChatroomsController` requires a user to be logged in in order to create a chatroom, so I have created a `Api::SessionsHelper` module to create sessions from within the `Api::ChatroomsController` spec.

```
# app/helpers/api/sessions_helper.rb
module Api::SessionsHelper
  def current_user
    User.find_by_session_token(session[:session_token])
  end

  def create_session(user)
    session[:session_token] = user.reset_session_token!
  end

  def destroy_session(user)
    current_user.try(:reset_session_token!)
    session[:session_token] = nil
  end
end


# spec/controllers/api/chatrooms_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'
include Api::SessionsHelper

RSpec.describe Api::ChatroomsController, type: :controller do
  before(:all) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    User.create!({username: "test_user", password: "asdfasdf"})
  end

  user = User.find_by_username("test_user")

  context "with valid params" do
    done = false

    # doesn't work if using a before(:all) hook
    before(:each) do
      until done do
        create_session(user)
        post :create, chatroom: { name: "chatroom 1" }
        done = true
      end
    end

    let(:chatroom) { Chatroom.find_by({name: "chatroom 1"}) }
    let(:chatroom_member) { ChatroomMember.find_by({user_id: user.id, chatroom_id: chatroom.id}) }

    it "responds with a successful status code" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end

    it "creates a chatroom in the database" do
      expect(chatroom).not_to eq(nil)
    end

    it "adds the chatroom creator to the ChatroomMember table" do
      expect(chatroom_member).not_to eq(nil)
    end
  end

end
```

I'm using a `before(:each)` hook with a boolean variable `done` to achieve the behavior of a `before(:all)` hook for creating a single session.

If I use a before(:all) hook, I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass`
```

I put a debugger in the create_session method of the Api::SessionsHelper module to check `self.class` and in both cases, when I use `before(:each)` and when I use `before(:all)`, the class is:

```
RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApiChatroomsController::WithValidParams
```

However when using the `before(:each)` hook, session is `{}`, while in the `before(:all)` hook, session gives the `NoMethodError` above.

Anybody know what causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the helper in the test block:

```
RSpec.describe Api::ChatroomsController, type: :controller do
  include Api::SessionsHelper
end
```

You can also avoid duplication by including common spec helpers in `spec/rails_helper.rb`

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  config.include Api::SessionsHelper, type: :controller
end
```

This is also where you should put the database_cleaner config. You should use to clean between every spec not just before all as that will lead to test ordering issues and flapping tests.

```
require 'capybara/rspec'

#...

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include Api::SessionsHelper, type: :controller
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    if config.use_transactional_fixtures?
      raise(<<-MSG)
        Delete line `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` from rails_helper.rb
        (or set it to false) to prevent uncommitted transactions being used in
        JavaScript-dependent specs.

        During testing, the app-under-test that the browser driver connects to
        uses a different database connection to the database connection used by
        the spec. The app's database connection would not be able to access
        uncommitted transaction data setup over the spec's database connection.
      MSG
    end
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, type: :feature) do
    # :rack_test driver's Rack app under test shares database connection
    # with the specs, so continue to use transaction strategy for speed.
    driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs = Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test

    if !driver_shares_db_connection_with_specs
      # Driver is probably for an external browser with an app
      # under test that does *not* share a database connection with the
      # specs, so use truncation strategy.
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.append_after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Comment: There are also several other issues like you should learn how to use [`let`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let) instead of ivars or using lexical vars like `user = User.find_by_username("test_user")`.

Comment: Your general methodology is also wrong - you should be using the setup and teardown phase (`before` and `after`) to wipe the slate clean and then setup each example individually. Using `before_all` to setup some sort of state to be used by all the examples in a file is a very flawed approach.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm fairly new to writing specs.  Is `capybara` necessary if my controllers only render json?  Also I tried moving the `include Api::SessionsHelper` within the test block, as well as into the rails helper, and both cases still give me the same error when trying to use `create_session` in a `before(:all)` hook.

Comment: " Is capybara necessary if my controllers only render json?" - No its not. Capybara is a web crawler that parses HTML and simulates a user clicking his way around in the application. If you are writing an API only application you want to use request specs and ensure that the responses from the API match the docs for your API.

Comment: You're not supposed to use it in a `before_all` hook! You need to setup the state for each example. Use `before` and make sure you sign the user out by resetting the session after each example.

Comment: Thanks, I took your advice to reset the database for each test.  It's still a mystery to me though why the error thrown was `NoMethodError: undefined method 'session' for nil:NilClass` when using the `before(:all)` hook.  `self.class` are both `RSpec::ExampleGroups::ApiChatroomsController::WithValidParams` when putting the debugger inside the `create_session` method of the SessionsHelper module.  I would have thought that `self.class` would be `nil` to match the error when using `before(:all)`.